# Reading Binary Data with streambuf in C++ through a Class

Tags: c++, object, constructor, streambuf

Im am a c programmer trying to begin a new phase of my life in c++ (i know i am still using printf below, but that because formatting is so easy).  I am looking to print out the first byte of a datafile from a member function of an object.   I think my streambuffer is being destroyed before I can read it's data but I'm lost as to what to do.

My class looks like the following

```
class MyParser {
    MyParser(string filepath);
    void readHeader();

    streambuf *pbuf;
    long size;
}
```

My constructor opens the file, gets the buffer out, outputs the first byte and returns.  (I think `pbuf` is dying at the end of this code).  This code outputs `First Byte (in constructor): 0x8C`

```
MyParser::MyParser(string filepath) {
    ifstream file(filepath.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary)
    pbuf = file.rdbuf();
    size = pbuf->pubseekoff(0,ios::end,ios::in);
    pbuf->pubseekpos(0,ios::in);

    unsigned char byte = pbuf->sgetc();
    printf("First Byte (in constructor): 0x%02X\n", byte);

    return;
}
```

My read header is dumping the first byte, but based on the output all is see is `First Byte (in readHeader): 0xFF`

```
void MyParser::readHeader() {
    unsigned char byte = pbuf->sgetc();
    printf("First Byte (in readHeader): 0x%02X\n", byte);
}
```

My main simply creates a parser and tries to readHeader

```
void main() {
    MyParser parser("../data/data.bin");
    parser.readHeader();
}
```

I think the solution to my problem is to create a `new` streambuffer but `new streambuf(file.rdbuf())` isn't working for me.  Any advice?

Comment: Why are you using the buffer instead of the [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) / [`tellg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) and [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) functions in the [`istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) class?

Comment: i was following the example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/rdbuf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior: the stream buffer you keep is owned by the `std::ifstream` you open in body of you constructor. When this object dies, the stream buffer is released as well. The easiest approach to avoid this problem is to have your `std::ifstream` be a member of your class: this binds the life-time of the stream to your object. It may also be easier to use the `std::istream` interface for your parsing rather than the somewhat awkward `std::streambuf` interface.

If you really want to just use a stream buffer, you can allocate a `std::filebuf` using `new filebuf` and the `open()` the file stream directly. To keep a pointer to it, you would probably use `std::unique_ptr<std::filebuf>` (or `std::auto_ptr<std::filebuf>` if you are not using C++ 2011). Using the pointer class arranges for automatic release of the object. Of course, the pointers would still be members of your class to get the life-times right.

Your attempt to copy a stream buffer didn't work because stream buffers are not copyable. You'd need to create the file buffer directly:

```
MyParser::MyParser(std::string const& filename)
    : pbuf(new std::filebuf)
{
    this-pbuf->open("whatever", std::ios_base::in);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Keeping filestream as a member and opening the file in the init list worked.  I'm trying to write something that will eventually read binary data out of a binary network data stream so I feel that reading the whole buffer into memory will require more changes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need some new C++ teaching material, because (sorry) but this is just so wrong. You need to declare the filestream as a member, there's no need for any `new` anywhere in this program,  and pretty much nobody, ever, needs to deal with `streambuf`.

```
class MyParser {
    std::ifstream file;
public:
    MyParser(string filepath) {
        file.open(filepath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary );
        char byte;
        file.read(sizeof(byte), &byte);
        printf("First Byte (in constructor): 0x%02X\n", byte);        
    }
    void readHeader() {
        char byte;
        file.read(sizeof(byte), &byte);
        printf("First Byte (in readHeader): 0x%02X\n", byte);   
    }
};
```

Comment: parameters are backwards on your read, should be pointer,size not size,pointer.